# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL and SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG with a specific ISP only

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

When accessing https://mcgillcrm.com some users are seeing this in chrome: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL` and this is firefox: `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`

But it only happens when they access the site through a specific ISP (Videotron).

When the site is accessed via a hotspot or when connected to a different ISP it works fine and it also works if the user is using Windows machine instead of a Mac.

I verified [SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mcgillcrm.com), checked port 443 and compared against another site where it doesn't throw this error and everything seems fine.

We have a 301 redirect towards https and I double checked that users really type https:// when accessing the web-site, but it still doesn't work.

[image]

#### How is the connection done to the ISP vs. how is the connection done to a different ISP or mobile network

- Mac user connects to the wireless modem: SSL errors come up
- Mac user connects to the wireless mobile hotspot: No error comes up

#### Update 12 Oct 2022

We re-installed a new certificate from scratch and this one is not showing 'self signed' anywhere. Will see if it helps.

Comment: Getting the same type of error, only with one site (https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/), when using my home ISP, but not when using mobile internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turned out to be with safebrowse.io which was somehow caching the incorrect certificate (clearing SSL cert in chrome didn't help).

It in turn affected other browsers also like Firefox. So once the incorrect cert was cached it flagged it globally as an unsafe site..

It looks like it was cached inside the logged in users chrome profile (Google Workspace account).

Solution was to login as Guest > Go to web-site > Click 'Proceed anyway' > Restart Chrome

[image]

[image]

This looks like a serious design flaw with safebrowse.io, why/how it caches SSL certificates in Chrome profile is unclear. This should have worked while accessing the web-site in Chrome incognito but it didn't..

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is end to end encryption and integrity protection. It should not depend on the ISP used by the client. If it is specific only to the ISP or specific clients then something is messed up at their end, like some middleboxes or antivirus interfering with the connection, a captive portal asking the client to acknowledge some rules first, DNS resolution pointing to a different IP then yours etc. There is nothing you can do from the server end against this, since maybe the server is not even reached by the client.

Comment: thank you, would changing the certificate help? if I reinstall it and use a different provider?

Comment: @RobertSinclair: unlikely.

Comment: to make matters more strange, it works using the same ISP but if the user's on a PC not a Mac.. so if it's a specific ISP + Mac then it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertSinclair: How is the connection done to the ISP vs. how is the connection done to a different ISP or mobile network?

Comment: They connect via the browser or did you mean something else? Wonder if there's a way to run some sort of a command in terminal when the user is on hotspot vs mobile to see the difference, like a traceroute?

Comment: @RobertSinclair: connection using a ISP is usually done via a router or modem, so different ISP means either different routers or different setups for same router. Similar connection to mobile network is done with mobile phone tethering or some router capable of using mobile networks. I want to know this detail to find out what components (software, hardware, devices, configuration ...) are all different in case of working vs. non-working.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will collect the specifics and update the question with all the details. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question. In the section: "How is the connection done to the ISP vs. how is the connection done to a different ISP or mobile network"

Comment: @RobertSinclair:  It might be that their ISP returns the wrong IP address for the domain which results in connecting to the wrong host. The working Windows system might have another name server configured. But that's just speculation. If there are multiple users which all experience the same problem with this single ISP, it might be useful to contact the support of the ISP.